# Starting out with Python and Web Scraping... I don't quite understand why this isn't working?

Tags: python, for-loop

I used the following code, to try and insert a new line after each comma that appeared after the html text was printed, to seprate the links that I was trying to find using beautifulSoup (Since they appeared as a text with commas indicating differernt links, and I wanted to seperate them). I tried this, and it doesn't seem to do anything...and I don't know why?

```
file = requests.get(url) 
UsualError = file.text
Extractor = BeautifulSoup(UsualError)
run = print(Extractor.find_all('link'))
for text in run: 
    if ',':
        +"/n";
print(run)
```

I tried other methods aswell, but I don't think they were entirely right....and I'm not too sure how to go about this, so if someone could point out, what I'm thinking is extremely obvious, you'll be helping somoene get to grips with something :)

Comment: Did you mean: `for text in run: print(text)`?

Comment: I think you should replace 'link' by 'a' if you want to get hyperlinks.

Comment: To clarify for the comments; @mkrieger1m, what I meant was for a newline to be inserted in the text of run, every time a comma is present. does that make sense?

Comment: As for @Corralien, sorry, I was simply trying to play around with using .find_all, so I wanted to have the HTML for the <link></link> in its entirety.

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `print(UsualError)` for a better understanding, please?

Comment: Where the code says `if ',':` and then `+"/n";`, I have absolutely no idea what you intend for that part to do, or how you expect it to work.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, could you explain in detail why it wouldn't work, please? I'm struggling to get my head around it a little :3.

Comment: @Corralien, The output is sensitive so I wouldn't like to share that, however, I can try and explain it. The output is essentially a very unclear format of HTML with all the 'link's that I tried to find, with commas separating them. They're one after the other, hence why I would like to insert some newlines where the commas appear to make it clearer. Does that make sense?

Comment: "could you explain in detail why it wouldn't work, please?" This isn't possible, because I can't even tell what you think "work" means here. You first. You wrote the code that says `if ',':`. What do you think that code should do? Why do you think it should do that?

Comment: My **strong** advice to you is to find a Python tutorial and learn the fundamentals of the language from start to finish. **Do not** try to invent your own projects or tasks, and **do not** try to use third-party libraries like BeautifulSoup, or attempt anything complicated, until you have considerable experience with writing *working* code that does *small* things.

Comment: If you write `if ","`, why should the interpreter (your terminology is fine) know that this should have anything to do with the text? Where is that concept expected to come from? How should Python know **what** the `","` has to do with text? There are any number of ways that a comma could be related to the text. For that matter, where do you think the newline should be added? (By the way, a newline is `\n`, not `/n`.) Immediately after the comma? How should it know that? `+` means to put the strings next to each other. A computer **cannot read your mind**.

Comment: "I've tried PY4E" - [here](https://www.py4e.com/html3/03-conditional) is the part where it explains, step by step, how to write an `if` statement, and carefully explains what is necessary. If you want to use `if`, you need to write an *expression* that *describes what has to be true* for the marked part of the code to run. `","` does not communicate "there is a comma in the text", "there is a comma at the end of the text", "the text is exactly equal to a comma", or anything else like that. (those also are all different things, so there would be no way to guess which one without being told.)

Comment: I see, and thank you for the link, that's something I haven't come across, so that's really helpful. So would I have to use a comparison operator, and correct the expression used? If I may, I'd like to ask you to continue lending me a hand on this.  I thought that the same way += or =+ could be used to add 1 in an expression, the + could be used to indicate a coagulation (the joining of words by the expression A + B.). I _know_ that a computer can't read my mind. But trying to understand the fundamental parameters of the computer takes some time. So please, do continue your assistance.

Comment: And if I may, could you show the difference in code between "there is a comma in the text", "there is a comma at the end of the text", and 'the text is exactly equal to a comma"? Would it be possible if I said that one would have to traverse the entire string/output(?) and use an expression to indent/create a new line in the text at every comma, or /n (thank you for pointing that out)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There might be no commas in the links. All the links are stored in a python list where all the entries in a python list are separated by a comma. So you cannot replace those commas with anything.

The main issue with your code is `run = print(Extractor.find_all('link'))`; you are assigning a print statement to `run`.

If you want to see all the contents as such:

```py
file = requests.get(url) 
UsualError = file.text
Extractor = BeautifulSoup(UsualError)
run = Extractor.find_all('link')
for text in run: 
    print(text)
```

If you want to see only the hyperlinks:

```py
file = requests.get(url) 
UsualError = file.text
Extractor = BeautifulSoup(UsualError)
run = Extractor.find_all('link')
for text in run: 
    print(text.get('href')
```

If you want to store only href links in the list `run`:

```py
file = requests.get(url) 
UsualError = file.text
Extractor = BeautifulSoup(UsualError)
run = Extractor.find_all('link')
run = [text.get('href') for text in run]

# now run contains only href links
# optionally you can print
# print(run)
# but commas can be seen between each link entry, as it is syntactically mandatory
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that perhaps what I asked was a little confusing, but you've still managed to take it and help me understand not only more about what I'm trying to do but also show me how to do many things with the code too. For the first time I've made a question, I'm grateful to you, for giving me a proper interaction, and a proper answer :)

Comment: Also as a follow-up, the reason why the code I used didn't work was that those commas couldn't be replaced?

Comment: Three issues: 1. when you assign print statement to run, run becomes `None`, so for loop is never executed. 2. assuming you enter into for loop, `if ','` is always equal to `True`, so you pass the conditional statement always. It is not about comma in the contents of run. 3. starting a statement with `+` is incorrect, so you will face TypeError.

Comment: I'm quite curious, what is it that has given you a deep understanding of these issues? I've tried my hand at a few books on coding and played around with it on occasion for a few months and off, but I can't seem to find anything that would be as informative as what you've just plainly told me. Why does run become None? What does that mean? Why is the `if ','` always equal to true? Sorry for asking all these questions, but I feel as though what you might tell me would be very helpful indeed! :)

Comment: 1. There are in-place operations/functions that won't return anything. There, python will return `None`. `print` is a in-place function, it prints arguments provided to it, but it doesn't return anything. If you assign `run = print()`, then the value of run is `None`. You can verify this by `print(run)`.  2. For every datatype (int, float, list, str) only one value is considered as equivalent to `False`. For int, 0; for float, 0.0; for string, ''(an empty string). In your case, you provided a string with comma `','` which is equivalent to `True`. You can verify by `print(bool(','))`

Comment: If I may ask again, how do you know all this? I've tried books and tutorials, and they wouldn't give me such a deep understanding. Where did you come to understand this?